# Can someone explain what I am suppose to solve/do for these two problems.

Tags: functions

Use the one-to-one correspondences $\ln: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $f: (2, \infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$, where $f(x) = x-2$, to describe a one-to-one correspondence.

(h) from $(2, \infty)$ onto $\mathbb R
$

(j) from $\mathbb R$ onto $(2, \infty)
$

I haven't put any work down because I don't know what to do. I am just looking for some guidance so I can dig into the problems afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say $\ln : (0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$? That is, the natural logarithm?

Comment: @PeterFranek I fixed it lol

Comment: The question "what [am I] suppose[d] to solve/do" in the title is not well researched.  Are you clear on the meaning of *one-to-one correspondence*?  Do you know how this property of a function is preserved in *composition of functions*?  From your quoting of the assignment it seems there were originally other parts, which should have given you the insight of "what to do" and how to "dig into the problems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means they want you to compose those functions you are given, to create the *one-to-one* correspondences (also known as *bijections*) from the given sets into the given sets.